# Update production database asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

We have a development asp.net core project (using git for revision control) that we want to bring in production. We are working as a team (3 members) at the project and we all have a local development database running (with our local migrations files not pushed to git repo).

What is the best way to update the production database when a new version of the application is ready (knowing that a new member should be able to update the database as well, starting from no migrations files)? What do we push (sql, migrations,...) to git?

**Info**

- Database: PostgreSQL
- EF core

Comment: You are not saying anything about what kind of database you are using. Maybe it's SQL Server or some other kind of relational database?

Let's assume it is SQL Server you are using. My opinion is that you should use a migration framework and make sure all your developers are pushing migrations to the repo. Then you can just run the migrations in sequence on the production database. Any new developer could also run the migrations to get from 0 to current version. Have a look at DbUp or EntityFramework :)

Comment: Database is postgresql. We are using EF core. Won't it gave conflicts if all of us push their migration files to the same folder in git?

Comment: Well, the thing is that when you have an application that is using a single database for persistance, you are required to keep the migrations in sync. Your team members have to communicate to make sure that they create migrations that won't create conflicts. If two users try to push conflicting migrations, they have to talk to each other and resolve the conflict :) No different than if they have a conflict in regular application code.